# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I can see the list of cars and their info but I wanted to see the details of individual car by typing like *car/details/tesla*. I am passing make of type string as parameter to details action method in CarController class but keep on getting null error when inspecting.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get returned null.

Thanks for any help

**CarController.cs**

```
public class CarController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult List()
    {
        List<Car> cars = DB.GetCars();
        return View(cars);
    }

    public IActionResult Detail(string make)
    {
        Car car = DB.GetCar(make);
        return View(car);
    }
}
```

**DB.cs**

```
public class DB
{
    public static List<Car> GetCars()
    {
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>()
        {
            new Car()
            {
                VIN = 12321,
                Make = "Toyota",
                Model = "Camry",
                Year = 2009,
                Color = "Black",
                Price = 32000
            },
            new Car()
            {
                VIN = 12323,
                Make = "Nissan",
                Model = "Altima",
                Year = 2020,
                Color = "Red",
                Price = 45000
            },
            new Car()
            {
                VIN = 12325,
                Make = "Tesla",
                Model = "Model 3",
                Year = 2021,
                Color = "Black",
                Price = 86000
            },
        };

        return cars;
    }

    public static Car GetCar(string make)
    {
        List<Car> cars = DB.GetCars();

        foreach (Car car in cars)
        {
            if(car.Make == make)
            {
                return car; 
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Car.cs**

```
public class Car
{
    public int VIN { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

**Details.cshtml**

```
@model Car

Make: @Model.Make

Year: @Model.Year

Color: @Model.Color
```

Comment: You should check for `if( car == null )` before calling `View( car )`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in `string` comparison. your URL is `car/details/tesla` and you are getting `tesla` as a `Maker` where as in your dataset it's `Tesla`.

So, you must be care about two points

1. Check if your `car` database is null or not based on `make`.
2. Ignore case sensitive, while string comparison.

Your `GetCar()` method should be following.

```
public static Car GetCar(string make)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(make)) return null;
    
    var cars = DB.GetCars()?.Where(c = c.Make?.Equals(make, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)?.ToList();

    return cars;
}
```

Note:

Instead of using `forEach`, I have used `LINQ` for filtering records.